# Trouble understanding this code snippet (creating an alphabet object and returning how many of them in a string provided)

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

Basically, I do not understand the way the code is bring written for the section I have commented out. All I know is that the code returns the numbers for each of the alphabets in the string provided.
For example:
"hello" returns {h:1, e:1, l:2, o:1}.
It would be helpful if anyone can explain to me or provide a less abstract way of writing this code, I will appreciate it a lot. Cheers!

```
function isAnagram(string1, string2){
    if(string1.length !== string2.length){;
        return false;
    }
    let freqCounter1 = {};
    let freqCounter2 = {};
    

    /*
    for(let val of string1){
        freqCounter1[val] = (freqCounter1[val] || 0) + 1;
    }
    for(let val of string2){
        freqCounter2[val] = (freqCounter2[val] || 0) + 1;
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) for..of loop**

First, you need to understand there is a [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

> The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects,
> including: built-in String, Array, array-like objects (e.g., arguments
> or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It
> invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the
> value of each distinct property of the object. - MDN

for..of loop iterates over the string and in each loop come with a single character in a variable `val`

```js
const str = "Hello";

const obj = {};

for (let val of str) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

So it comes in the sequence `H`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`

****2)** `(freqCounter1[val] || 0)`**

This is the use of OR operator, what it indicates is if `freqCounter1[val]` is falsy value i.e undefined, null, 0, etc. then the value of `(...)` expression in parenthesis is `0`

So in the first iteration `val` is `H` and the expression `(freqCounter1[val] || 0)` evaluates as `undefined || 0` which makes whole expression value as `0` because there is no property `H` in `freqCounter1` object.

****3)** `freqCounter1[val] = (freqCounter1[val] || 0) + 1;`**
Now the expression

`freqCounter1[val] = (freqCounter1[val] || 0) + 1;`

becomes

`freqCounter1[val] = 0 + 1;` because (because `(freqCounter1[val] || 0)` is 0)

So what it does is creating a property `H` in `freqCounter1` with value `1`

---

So the iteration goes on and on till the second `l` i.e. index `3`

Now `val` is `l`

so when it comes to expression `(freqCounter1[val] || 0)`

since `freqCounter1[val]` i.e `freqCounter1["l"]` has value i.e `1` which is a truthy value so the value of the whole expression will be `1`

so `freqCounter1[val] = (freqCounter1[val] || 0) + 1;`

means

`freqCounter1["l"] = 1 + 1;`

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation, wasn't expecting such a detailed answer but yea, thanks a ton.